# Replace `process.env.XXX` with environment variables

Tags: reactjs

I am building a React app where I need to use environment variables set in `.env` within javascript files hosted under the public folder (e.g. `/public/sw.js`).

Ideally, within `.env` I could have:

```
MY_URL="Hello world"
```

Then within `/public/sw.js` I could use:

```js
console.log(process.env.MY_URL);
```

When I run `yarn start` I would want `console.log(process.env.MY_URL)` to be replaced with `console.log("MY_URL")` before SPA is served.

My needs are really that straightforward.

The server this app will eventually be hosted on will not have a `.env` file which is why my preference would be the simple swap and replace value shown above. My expectation is that this is a one-time action each time the application is run or built; meaning `yarn start` or `yarn build` can replace `/public/sw.js` (or any other `.js` file containing a `process.env` reference.

Comment: on the Node side, use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), and on the client side: bundle them in using whatever bundler you're using (so: read the bundler docs on how to get environment variables in your bundle, and make 500% sure you're not including env vars that are API keys, auth values, etc. etc.)

Comment: Do you have any examples, because every time I run `node -r dotenv/config public/sw.js` all it does is output it to the console. It doesn't update `/public/sw.js`, which is what I want.

Comment: no, you install dotenv as a regular dependency, and then you load dotenv at the top of whichever .js file is your main file (either using `import` or `require` depending on whether you're working on new, or legacy code), to get all your `.env` values added to `process.env`. Just like the docs tell you.